# How to edit tag definitions?

Tags: discussion, support

@Chris recently wrote definitions for some tags. (I appreciate that a lot!)
There are certain small spelling and grammatical errors in those definitions. I want to help improve those.

How to edit these tag definitions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I am using a bit of my spare time to fill in at least some description for the empty tags. I would appreciate it, if some more people would join me there (there are still so many empty tags).

If you spot an error in a tag decription, simply click on "edit", either in the tag wiki or in the description window which opens, when you hover about a tag.
You can than edit the tag, when you have more than 1250 reputation points. If you have less than 4000, than your edits will have to be reviewed.

Comment: You can also click improve rather than approve for those with the review tag wiki edits privilege

Comment: @RoryM I only get options to approve, decline or skip tag revisions (not improve), but that is maybe due to reputation. Similarly to biogirl, I also thought about editing some suggested tag definitions before approving.

Comment: That's interesting, does anyone else have an improve button over 1500 rep?

Comment: @RoryM When I click to edit a tag wiki it says: "*You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.*". The tag wiki editing privilege comes with [Trusted user](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). However, I can still review and approve edits made by others, but apparently not re-edit them directly.

Comment: @fileunderwater Ahh - I would imagine that would be as you can't have more than one suggested edit pending per post making a review requiring improvement impossible